# Do I need to replace all 4 switches on my Whirpool WFE366LVS0 electric oven?

Tags: electrical-panel, switch, stove, radiant-heating

When I turn on any burner on my Whirpool WFE366LVS0 Electric range, it immediately goes on high heat and stays regardless of heat setting the knob is on. Should I replace all 4 Infinite switches as all the burners are doing this?  Or is there another part that connects all 4 that needs replacing?

Comment: I find it very improbably that ALL of your heat controls have failed at the same time.  My guess here is that there is an overall or "master" control board in the unit that has failed.

Comment: Shortened the question and removed the part about "igniter", as electric stoves tend not to ignite.

Comment: Is this a new stove, a new problem?

Comment: Most likely someone has been messing with the range wiring, and caused this problem. There may be a wiring diagram pasted on the back or inside. Find it and follow it.

Comment: If there's a wiring diagram a photo would help.   Could be in the manual, or in a document taped to the back or inside the back cover, or in an envelope taped or screwed to the outside or inside of the range, or glued to either side of the back cover.

Comment: @FreeMan  LOL'd at your cleaver comment.  Yeah, it would be really  bad if an electric range "ignited" .   I have to agree with jwh20 that it's not the switches, probably a control board or other electronics issue.   Appliance repair questions are hard to help with..   I certainly don't have the expertise.

Comment: I can only find an oven control wiring diagram for this model. The control board definitely doesn't control the burners based on that wiring diagram. I'm seconding what @jay613 said: can you please provide a wiring diagram? It will help greatly.

Comment: Getting ahead of myself here (should wait for wiring diagram) but I think that model is a ceramic cooktop, I think most ceramic cooktops are thermostatically controlled, and I think therefore the logic board theory is probably correct given the symptoms.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Will check out the wiring diagram and logic board before buying any infinite switch.  The stove is at least 8 years old I think and problem has been there for a few months.